# How to add current high_voltage page name as a body class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, helper

I was wondering how I might echo out the current high_voltage page name as class for my `<body>`?

My current solution is a bit cumbersome:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body class="<%= yield :body_class %>">

# app/views/pages/principles.html.erb
<% content_for :body_class do %>home<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a view helper that will return a string with controller name, action, id, etc.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def body_class
    "#{controller_name} #{controller_name}-#{controller.action_name} #{page_id}"
  end

  def controller_name
    controller.controller_path.gsub('/','-')
  end

  def page_id
    params['id']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@harlow
Nice solution, though I find it exposes to much information about the guts of my Rails app (that is the usage of 'high_voltage').

Also I don't need the `params['id']` outside the context of 'high_voltage' pages contained in the class(es) for the body- or in my case html-tag.

I use this one:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def html_class
    "#{controller.controller_name} #{controller.action_name} #{page_id}"
  end

  def page_id
    return params['id'].gsub('/','-') if controller.controller_name == 'pages'
    return nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice try for the simplicity and less lines of code but this throws an error saying `undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass` when I am on a non-HighVoltage page. @harlow's solution works though.